# JQUERY. Dynamicaly changing images with .each() waiting for full load to remove loader

Tags: jquery, image, load, each, loader

Please help.
I was googling for answer for my problem, but cannot find any solution.

I'm getting image names from PHP file using $.post()

I have page with thumbnail of images on the page but without any src. 
After it read names from file, it change those src'es to those it got.

I want to let them all load in hidden mode and with loader on it, and then remove loader and fadeIn my images.

Loader starts, then hides but images still continuing to load. 
What i'm doing wrong?

Tons of thanks.

here part of my code:
HTML:

```
<div id="window">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div class="container" style="left:10px; top:10px;"><img class="image" /></div>
                <div class="container" style="left:120px; top:10px;"><img class="image" /></div>
                <div class="container" style="left:230px; top:10px;"><img class="image" /></div>
                <div class="container" style="left:340px; top:10px;"><img class="image" /></div>
                <div class="container" style="left:450px; top:10px;"><img class="image" /></div>

                <div class="container" style="left:10px; top:120px;"><img class="image" /></div>
                <div class="container" style="left:120px; top:120px;"><img class="image" /></div>
                <div class="container" style="left:230px; top:120px;"><img class="image" /></div>
                <div class="container" style="left:340px; top:120px;"><img class="image" /></div>
                <div class="container" style="left:450px; top:120px;"><img class="image" /></div>

                <div class="container" style="left:10px; top:230px;"><img class="image" /></div>
                <div class="container" style="left:120px; top:230px;"><img class="image" /></div>
                <div class="container" style="left:230px; top:230px;"><img class="image" /></div>
                <div class="container" style="left:340px; top:230px;"><img class="image" /></div>
                <div class="container" style="left:450px; top:230px;"><img class="image" /></div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

JS:

```
$('#wrapper').append('<div class="loading"></div>');
$.post('dirscan.php', {'dir':dir},
    function(data){

        imagNames = data;
        ImgCount = imagNames.length;
        totalPages = parseInt(ImgCount / 15) - 1;
        if ((totalPages % 15) != 0) { totalPages++ };

        $('img.image').each(function(i){
            if (imagNames[(pageN*15)+i]) {
                $(this).attr('src', imagNames[(pageN*15)+i])
            }
            else { $(this).addClass('close') }
        })

        $('img.image').load(function(){
            $('.loading').fadeOut(500);
            $('img.image').fadeIn(700);
            $('.loading').remove();})

},'json');
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the way!

```
$('img.image').each(function(i){
if (imagNames[(pageN*15)+i]) {
$(this).attr('src', imagNames[(pageN*15)+i])
    $(this).load(function(){
$('.loading').fadeOut(500);
$(this).fadeIn(700); //here is the key
$('.loading').remove();})
```

Hope will help to anyone.